# How do I disable output for jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

After upgrading to the latest official release of [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/):

For PHP UploadHandler.php I'm getting output similar to:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "name": "1367159262-79",
        "size": 0,
        "type": "multipart\/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d115d2a20060c",
        "error": "abort",
        "delete_url": "http:\/\/my-site.com\/photos\/?file=1367159262-79",
        "delete_type": "DELETE",
        "id": null
    }]
}
```

Our apps are choking on this output.

If I set the print_response to false for the post method like so I no longer see the above output which works great on the app side.  Unfortunately when I do this I now see: ***Empty file upload result*** after uploading a file via the web.

```
return $this->generate_response(
       array($this->options['param_name'] => $files),
       false
);
```

Any idea how I can eliminate this JSON output and not get the ***Empty file upload result*** error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding an argument to the cosntructor for UploadHandler and setting it to false for the apps.  There might be a better way but it solves the issues for me:

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null, $print_response = true) {
    ...
}
```

For the apps I did this:

```
$options = null;
$initialize = true;
$error_messages = null;
$print_response = false;

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options, $initialize, $error_messages, $print_response);
```